# EF5 issues - table splitting

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I'm having issues with table splitting because I need the same table columns in both entities.  Is there a way of doing that?

My example scenario.

Table MESSAGES has id, sourcesystemid, destinationsystemid
Table SYSTEMS has id and name

To get the source system name and destination system name I link to the same SYSTEMS table, example SQL would be

SELECT m.id, s.name, d.name
 from messages m
 join systems s on s.id = m.sourcesystemid
 join systems d on d.id = m.destinationsystemid

I have table splitting working but not when both entities have the same columns.

ERROR
"are being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side properties"

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Maybe use inheritance in stead of table splitting?

Comment: Thanks Gert.  Error though.    A member named NAME cannot be defined in class IntegrationsInternaldevModel.sourceSystem1. It is defined in ancestor class IntegrationsInternaldevModel.sourceSystem.

Comment: If it's in the ancestor class it's also in the inherited class. No need to define it twice.